# Winforms - Notifying/Publishing events in a control hierarchy

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I have a hierarchy of controls like -

```
MainForm (has menus / toolbars)
      |____TabContainer
                  |_____TabPages
                               |_____TreeView...etc.
```

Now, after the data has been loaded in the TreeView and user selects a particular Node element - I want to notify the MainForm as well as some controls up in the hirarchy from the TreeView and change the controls(s) state accordingly based on the NodeClicked event.

I am maintaining a static EventMgr class where I publish all events and the the controls which are interested in particular events, listen to it. I know there are better ways to design such that Unit Testing becomes easy ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you considered a recursive call that just walks up all the parent controls of the control that was selected?  Rather than needing to use a maintained list?  I am not sure if that helps in this specific instance or not.

Comment: that will be very inefficient for every event triggered

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the Delegates will be a better option.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I am using Events. Please be elaborate